# How to access iOS NSCache folder using XC UI Testing tool?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, xctest

I need to access the iOS NSCache folder using XC UI Testing tool.If we cannot do this what are the workarounds available? What are the other UI Testing tools which supports this?

Answer (score 0):

`NSCache` doesn't store it's content on disk. It's only in-memory cache. So probably you meant `NSURLCache`?

If so, just initialize it with path:

```
NSURLCache *urlCache = 
[[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:1024 * 1024 
                              diskCapacity:1024 * 1024 * 5 
                                  diskPath:@"<PATH>"];
```

And later in XC UI Testing tool use same path.